# c++ 11 - Working with directories

Tags: c++, file, c++11, file-io, directory

I come from Python, and im looking to work with directories (browse, list, create dir, remove dir, move files, etc) like with os in python. Ive found a lot of tutorials online but they are all using older versions of c++, not 11 - and im trying not to mix syntax yet. I want to understand 11 before worrying about older stuff - As well as, im not sure if theres better ways in c++ 11 than the older things.

I saw a question mentiong http://www.boost.org/libs/filesystem/

which if it is widely suggested, ill dig into, but id really prefer to stick to the standard lib for now. can anyone point me to a c++11 header I would use and/or a tutorial on directory work with c++11? agian, I've come accross quite a few, but they all seem to be old - and im not sure of the search term i should be using (ie the header name) to find what i want.

Comment: file io is reading/writing correct? I have done a bit of that in practice (very basic.. still need to work on it) but i want to learn directory stuff first, as the 2 seem to go hand in hand in many cases.
So theres nothing that comes with c++ to work with drectories? that seems... odd. so i should get boost then?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about learning older C++ as it's still relevant and C++ 11 just builds on the existing language, so it will all be required and useful. It might actually be easier to learn C++ and then learn C++ 11 additions, and boost is a good library to consider as it will work with C++ with or without the C++ 11 standards.

Comment: @Curg : "*It might actually be easier to learn C++ and then learn C++ 11 additions*" Could not disagree more – range-based `for` and initializer lists, and lambdas to a lesser extent, are what makes C++11 easier to learn now than it used to be.

Comment: Well we can chose to disagree, C++ 11 may bring more features but it also bring more difficult to read code, and I'm a believer in starting at a simpler level and working your way up.
Learning to walk before running is my philosophy.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, filesystem is not yet in the standard, but it'll be largerly inspired from the boost filesystem. So, IMHO, you can use the boost library, and later switch to the standard with not too much work.
see [here](https://isocpp.org/std/status) for more information.

Comment: ahhhh the AFAIK threw me for a second xD gotcha. Thanks, I guess ill run with boost for now, seems to be the most suggested, and if you're saying it shouldnt be a large turn to the std later, all the better.

Comment: @user1917081 : As you can see in the [TR2 Filesystem proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3505.html), the standard filesystem functionality is directly based on Boost.Filesystem v3. (The actual technical specification draft is [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3940.html) if you're curious.)

Answer (score 1):

There is support in Boost for a directory listing. There is also [QDir](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html) in Qt. And there is `POSIX dirent.h` header that enables directory listing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(void) {
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    if ((dir = opendir ("/")) != NULL) {
        /* print all the files and directories within directory */
        while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
            printf ("%s\n", ent->d_name);
        }
        closedir (dir);
     } else {
        /* could not open directory */
        perror ("");
        return -1;
     }

     return 0;
}
```

There [is](http://www.softagalleria.net/dirent.php) also `dirent.h` for Windows.

http://ideone.com/yN64G0

Comment: Thanks! for whatever reason no one tends to recommend dirent to me... not sure why, do you know? If theres good reason, perhaps ill break down and go with boost.

Comment: no, I don't, this is POSIX specification, should be portable